# how to render returned data on prop change in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-api-gateway

I am having trouble figuring out how to get an API call to re-render to the screen. I have an apiCall function that passes this.state and changes the state via passed ref but it does not trigger a rerender on the props change.

searchBody.js

```
 class SearchBody extends Component {
constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      const queryString = require('query-string');
      const queryTerm = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
      this.state = { urlSearchTerm: queryTerm.search,
                      searchTerm: '',
                      loaded: false,
                      buttonClicked: null,
                      apiData: [],
                      tableHeaders: [],
                      tableRows: []
                    }
      // check if URL has search term if so pass term for apiCall
      if (this.state.urlSearchTerm) {
         this.state.searchTerm = this.state.urlSearchTerm
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }


// capture input text field to state variable
handleChange = searchTerm => event => {
  this.setState({ searchTerm: event.target.value })
  //console.log(this.state.searchTerm)
  }

// handle form submission
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  console.log('Inside HandleSubmit')
  console.log('button clicked update url to /?search=' + this.state.searchTerm)
  this.props.history.push('/?search=' + this.state.searchTerm);
  this.setState({buttonClicked: true})
  event.preventDefault();
}
// load search from API if search term is in URL
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('Inside compDidMount')
  if (this.state.urlSearchTerm){
      this.setState({apiData: apiCall(this.state)})
  }
 }

render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;

  let table = ''
  //check if API has loaded data and show results if true
if (this.state.loaded){
  if (this.state.apiData.length === 0 && this.state.buttonClicked){
    table = 'No Results Found'
    //reset search button State
    this.setState({buttonClicked: false})
  } else {
    table = <TableData tableHead={this.state.tableHeaders} tableData={this.state.tableRows} />
    //reset search button State
    this.setState({buttonClicked: false})
  }
}
    return (

      <Fragment>
      <hr/>
       <form /*className={classes.container}*/ noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <TextField
              id="search"
              label="Search field"
              type="search"
            /*  className={classes.textField}*/
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.handleChange('search')}
            />
            <Button color='primary' letiant="outlined" type="submit" >Search DB</Button>
        </form>

          <h1>Results: </h1>
              {table}
        </Fragment>
          )
  }

}
export default SearchBody
```

methods.js

```
// break API data into arry of data for table component rows.
export const parseTableHeaders = input => {
  // console.log(input)
  if (input !== undefined && input.length !== 0) {
  let head = []
  for(let key in input[0]){  head.push(key);}
  //console.log(head)
  return head
}
}

///break API data into array of headers for table component
export const parseTableRows = (input) => {
  let rows = [];
  for(let o in input) {
      rows.push(Object.values(input[o]));
  }
  //console.log(head)
  return rows
}


//get api data from AWS
export function  apiCall(props) {
  const searchTerm = props.searchTerm
  let apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;

  const config =  {
                //apiKey: 'xxxx',
                invokeUrl:'https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
                }

  let apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(config);
  let params = {
        //This is where any header, path, or querystring request params go. The key is the parameter named as defined in the API
        //  userId: '1234',
        search_keyword: searchTerm
      };
      // Template syntax follows url-template https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
  let pathTemplate = '/beta/testDB'
  let method = 'GET';
  let additionalParams = {
      //If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that need to be sent with the request you can add them here
      headers: { },
      queryParams: {
        search_keyword: searchTerm
              }
    }
    apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
      .then(function(result){
          //This is where you would put a success callback
          console.log('apiCall Returned. searchTerm; ', searchTerm)
          console.log(result)
          props.loaded = true
          props.tableHeaders = parseTableHeaders(JSON.parse(result.data))
          props.tableRows = parseTableRows(JSON.parse(result.data))
          return JSON.parse(result.data)
      }).catch( function(result){
          //This is where you would put an error callback
      })


}
```

Am I structuring the code wrong? My understanding is that when a prop changes it will force a re-render. Should I pass the "this.state.apiData" into apiCall instead of the entire state like this?

```
apiCall(this.state.apiData)
```

This is running within componentDidMount() I believe this is the correct location to call an API, but it's not re-rendering upon callback. I can see in the debugger the state variables are updating as expected.
Should I set a return variable in `apiCall()` and have the return value update the state within the componentDidMount()? Would this force a re-render once the data is returned?

something like this?

```
this.setState({apiData: apiCall()})
```

If I return this.state.apiData from apiCall() and have it parse the table headers and rows inside apiCall, when the state variable is returned will this force an update?

Comment: yes the structure is wrong, you are mutating the props object so React will not know that there is a change. The API call should return an object and then you should `setState` with the information. That will cause a re-render.

Comment: I updated the question and have the apiCall return the apiData and set the this.state.apiData variable to what is returned. Is my logic in the render wrong for showing the Table component? Should I just return this.state.loaded variable so the if statement in render works properly?

Comment: the api call is async, so you are setting state to be the promise of the api call but the promise is not resolved (could be argued as another form of mutation). You should call the API function and chain a .then on the response and use that to setState `apiCall().then( apiResponse => this.setState({ loaded: true, apiData: apiResponse })`

Comment: I tried returning true when the data callback runs so it will set this.state.loaded = true. but the console.log is showing that execution stops at the end of the apiCall callback. I'm updating the state variable in componentDidMount() with this.setState({loaded: apiCall(this.state)}) so I am lost as to why it is not rendering again.

Comment: lets take this to a chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171569/react-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric Hasselbring helped me get to this answer.
I was calling apiCall() and it was not returning anything inside of componentDidMount. I added return before the methods.js apigClient.invokeAPI() so that it would return the result of the function

```
  return apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
      .then(function(result){
          //This is where you would put a success callback
          console.log('apiCall Returned. searchTerm; ', searchTerm)
          console.log(result)
          debugger
          props.tableHeaders = parseTableHeaders(JSON.parse(result.data))
          props.tableRows = parseTableRows(JSON.parse(result.data))
          return JSON.parse(result.data)
      }).catch( function(result){
          //This is where you would put an error callback
      })
```

then I updated my function call from within SearchBody.js to

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('Inside compDidMount')
  if (this.state.urlSearchTerm){
      apiCall(this.state).then(apiResponse => this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        apiData: apiResponse
      })
    )
  }
 }
```

So now apiCall returns a result from a promise and the apiCall is now a promise because of the .then function added. this allows the state to be changed inside of componentDidMount so that react sees there was a prop change and re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

You are running an Async Call to get some rest api Data. Async by definition means you have no idea when your code will finish. This means you will need some type of callback to run after your apiCall has finished.

What you have here is a rest api call that returns a promise object. The promise object is basically an interface for adding callbacks to asynchronous code. I recommend you take one of these options for running a callback after your restApi call.

1.) You can pass a callback function into restApi() as a second parameter. You would invoke this callback as such:

```
let that = this;
apiCall(props, function(result) {
    that.setState({apiData: result});
});

export function  apiCall(props, callback) {
    ...
    apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
        .then(function(result){
            ...
            callback(result);
            ...
        });
    ...
}
```

2.) Your other option would be to handle the resolution of your apiCall by latching onto the promise that is created by the api call. When you execute async code the call to the async method immediately returns the promise object which you can return to the calling function to allow the caller to attach callbacks. this may sound a bit confusing, I am not the greatest at explaining things but see the following:

```
let that = this;
apiCall(props).then(function(result) {
    that.setState({apiData: result});
});

export function  apiCall(props) {
    ...
    return apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams)
    .then(function(result){
        ...
    });
}
```

The key difference here is that you are returning the actual async call to apigClient.invokeApi. this allows whoever calls apiCall() to attach any callback functionality in the .then() method.

Ultimately you want to make sure you are calling setState when the restApi data actually gets back to the caller. .then() is the easiest way to trigger that call and reliably get the returned result.

Note: you should also look into promises in JS as the .then method can accept 2 parameters, One function that handles the successful return of data and one that handles error reporting.